# Creation of index style files (complete references)

Tags: indexing

Where can I get the complete reference for creating the index style files in LaTeX?

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

read http://mirrors.ctan.org/indexing/makeindex/paper/ind.pdf