# How To Format an Index Alphabetically in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Index with an initial letter of the group](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65247/index-with-an-initial-letter-of-the-group)

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{\index*{Hello World}}

Hello World

Some text about \index*{foo}.

\lipsum[1-15]

\index*{Hello World}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Required Output:**

[image]

Please guide me how to achieve the desired Output.

Comment: What do you want? only the headins `X` with a gray bar in front?

Comment: Yes, I want Alphabetically Grouped Index Results under the Proper Alphabet Heading (as highlighted here).

Comment: In this case have closer look at the questions [Creation of index style files (complete references)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32941/creation-of-index-style-files-complete-references) and [Index with an initial letter of the group](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65247/index-with-an-initial-letter-of-the-group/65249#65249)